# Appending dataframes from right column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the following code, in every iteration, a csv file is read as a data frame and it is concatenated to an result data frame (initially empty) from right.

```
result = pd.DataFrame()
for bench in benchmarks:
    df = read_raw(bench)
    print(df)
    result = pd.concat([result, df], axis=1, join="inner")
print(result.info())
```

As you can see below, df is not empty, but final result is empty.

```
$ python3 test.py
                  launch
0                      1
1                    524
2                   3611
3                   3611
4                    169
...                  ...
92515                143
92516                138
92517                169
92518                138
92519               1048

[92520 rows x 1 columns]
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 0 entries
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   M1      0 non-null      int64
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove `join="inner"`.

```py
result = pd.concat([result, df], axis=1)
```

Setting argument `join="inner"` means that only indexes appear in both `result` and `df` will be concatenated. Since `result` is an empty dataframe with no index, the result of your `pd.concat` will always return empty dataframe.